# Why can't receive rtp stream on Ubuntu?

Tags: video, vlc, ffmpeg, streaming

I am streaming the desktop over rtp using ffmpeg from computer A. Here is my ffmpeg code:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 25 -video_size 1920x1080 -i :1.0 -c:v libx264 -preset fast -pix_fmt bgr0 -b:v 3M -g 25 -an -f rtp_mpegts rtp://230.0.0.1:5005
```

I can play the live stream in vlc in the computer A in "rtp://@230.0.0.1:5005". But I can't play the stream from computer B that is in the same network with computer A. If I stream an mp4 file over http, than computer B is able to play it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I couldn't see the file name on your command line? Where do you feed the file exactly?